# ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, conv-neural-network, tflearn

I am trying to build a CNN in Tflearn to process 360x390px images. I am testing it on a small dataset of 170 images before deploying to the actual dataset.
I am working on Jupyter notebook.

The model fitting phasecan start, but after a couple seconds it throws an error that I do not understand: `ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("strided_slice/stack_4:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)`

Full error log:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 491, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 577, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("strided_slice/stack_4:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 497, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 655, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3568, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 527, in apply_op
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'strides' of 'StridedSlice' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'begin'.
```

My network architecture seems to be ok though, I understand it is a type error but cannot pinpoint where it comes from.

X is a np array of size (batch,H,W,C); Y is a one_hot np array of size  (batch,C)

For info, my network looks like below:

```
mynet = input_data(shape=[None,H,W,C])

mynet = conv_2d(mynet,nb_filter=32,filter_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu',regularizer="L2")
mynet = max_pool_2d(mynet,2)
mynet = conv_2d(mynet,nb_filter=64,filter_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu',regularizer="L2")
mynet = max_pool_2d(mynet,2)
mynet = conv_2d(mynet,nb_filter=128,filter_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu',regularizer="L2")
mynet = max_pool_2d(mynet,2)

mynet = fully_connected(mynet,n_units=1024,activation='relu')
mynet = dropout(mynet,0.8)

mynet = fully_connected(mynet,n_units=3,activation='softmax')
mynet = regression(mynet,optimizer='adam',learning_rate=0.01,loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(mynet)

model.fit(X,Y, n_epoch=20, validation_set=0.15,shuffle=True,show_metric=True) # <== This is where I get the error
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It looks like you have defined input—which I am assuming is of type tf.int32. Change this to tf.int64. Thanks!